# Poincare' inequality for weak-$L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Does Poincare' inequality hold in $L^{p, \infty}(\Omega)$? Or, more precisely, say $1 \le p < \infty$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain. Is it true that there exists a constant $C = C(p, \Omega) > 0$, which depends only on $\Omega$ and $p$, such that for each function $u \in L^{p, \infty}(\Omega)$ with $\nabla u \in L^{p, \infty}(\Omega)$ one has
$$
\|u\|_{L^{p, \infty}(\Omega)} \le C(p, \Omega) \|\nabla u\|_{L^{p, \infty}(\Omega)} \qquad ?
$$

Comment: what is $L^{p,\infty}(\Omega) $?